# Display html text < ahref> in UITextview iOS

Tags: html, ios, attributes, textview

How can I display HTML tag like  in textview?

For example,

```
Hello good morning <a href=\"1\">USER1</a> and <a href=\"13\">USER2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *htmlString = @"Hello good morning <a href=\"1\">USER1</a> and <a href=\"13\">USER2</a>";

yourTextView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: but how to get return attributes string like <a href=\"1\">USER1</a>

Comment: means only dispay "Hello Good morning User1 and User2" but when i click on button we get actual string like "Hello good morning <a href=\"1\">USER1</a> and <a href=\"13\">USER2</a>"

Comment: i do not think that is is possible with my solution. you should store the htmlString somewhere before converting it to `NSData` and showing it in the textview...